# How to handle pagination in ADF loop for Google Analytics 4 v1beta API without nextPageToken value in response?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to get data from the new version of Google Analytics 4 version 1 beta.

In the old version, I could use pagination to get all the data for a large date range.
So, in Azure Data Factory I had a foreach loop activity, where the call to Google Analytics API was made until the nextPageToken value was 0.

Now I am trying to apply the same logic on the new version: https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/**propertyId**:runReport
I have read that I can use the offset for this problem, but I do not get the value of the nextPageToken in the response of the new version API.

Can someone please help me with this issue? Or more exactly, how can I handle pagination issue in ADF foreach loop for the new version of Google Analytics GA4 version 1 beta

Best regards!

Tried to get the nextPageToken value on the response body of the new Google Analytics API version 1 beta. I do not get the nextPageToken at all.

Comment: can I see the full report you are running

Comment: You mean the request body?

Comment: please edit your question and include a [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve the pagination of Google Analytics 4 version 1beta in ADF pipeline.
I have three set variable activities, set offset to 0, set limit to 100 000 and set total rows received to 0. Then I added an until activity with condition, until total rows received and row count (from the response) are the same.
Inside the Until activity, I update these 3 variables.

Hope this solution will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running a query with a predefined iterator that increments at 10,000 for every return you have. The API itself has an 'offset' parameter you can plug this iterated number through. If the length of the return has less than 10,000 elements (or rows if you're converting it to a data frame), then the query you're diving into doesn't have any more data to iterate through.

Pagination in the Analytics and Reporting APIs is not done by a page number attribute or property. Instead, Google caps its table return size to 10,000 rows. From what I understand, there are ways to pay and have some caps and quotas lifted, but the return size isn't one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
After going through the documentation of the new version, I do now understand the pagination. I will post how I solved it